# also have or have also

Tags: grammar, adverb-placement

Some websites have varying answers regarding the placement of **also**(adverb) whether it should precede before the auxillary 'have' or after. Such as:

> Whoever was in your shoes, they would **also** have done that.

Or

> Whoever was in your shoes, they would have **also** done that.

Moreover, I believe that this website can help me clarify this up, because from other websites they are just opinion, weak-based answers. What is your answer to this?

Comment: Unfortunately, it *is* mostly just a matter of opinion. Both versions are grammatical. It's up to individual style and preference which to use. Note that there are two more variations: (1) move **also** in front of *would*, and (2) move **also** to the end of the sentence.

Comment: Excellent! I was bothered by this because I thought there is only one specific grammar rule where to put this **also**. I already know you can put ''also'' at the end of a sentence accordingly, I just forgot to write it hehe. Thx, you nailed that one on the head!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between these 2 sentences are only a matter of opinion and preference, both:

> Whoever was in your shoes, they would **also** have done that.

and

> Whoever was in your shoes, they would have **also** done that.

Are grammatically correct.